# Issue creating cron proces

Tags: unix, cron

I'm having some trouble setting up a cron process and can't seem to determine why I keep getting this strange error:

```
MAILTO="me@myemail.com"
30 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 * * * sh /var/runner/process.sh > /var/runner/data/logs/$(date +"%-H").txt
30 23 * * * sh /var/runner/process.sh > /var/runner/data/logs/$(date + "%-H").txt
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Wondering what could be going wrong :-/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the date formatting with a single quotes and see if it helps?